# 3d Math Library For Python

Tags: python, math, 3d

i'm looking for a 3d math library in python or with python bindings.

it needs to handle rotation, translation, perspective projection, everything basically.

what im NOT looking for is a library aimed at drawing on the screen, googling for hours only led to 3d libraries bent on rendering something to the screen. i dont want any visualization whatsoever, all i need is to be able feed a library x,y,z coordinates and recieve the x,y screen coordinates.

i dont mind if its a visualization library, as long as it can be used without rendering anything to the screen.

is there anything like this for python?

Edit:
please dont recommend scipy/numpy as they arent aimed at 3d math but at math in general, they look like great tools if i wanted to build the library myself, which i dont. thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want? The transformations you are asking for can be done with matrix multiplications, which numpy is a natural fit for. Are you hoping to do 3d work without seeing any matrices at all?

Comment: python has good support for working with strings, does that mean everyone should roll their own XML parsing library? numpy is good for general math, but i cant just feed it (x,y,z) coords and have it present the 2d (x,y) coords, can i , i'd habe to use numpy to roll my own 3d math engine?

whats wrong with looking for a library to handle something as common as 3d geometry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [gameobjects](http://code.google.com/p/gameobjects/) -- it's a math library that includes Python classes for matrices and vectors, along with methods for transformations. I think it will provide most (if not all) of what you need, plus it's pure Python so you can modify it if you need to.

Comment: you win at the internet! thank you.

Answer (score 5):

[OpenCV - Python Interface](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/PythonInterface) can handle all the operations you've mentioned.

I hear [SciPy](http://www.scipy.org/)'s excellent for this as well, but I've only used OpenCV.

Comment: Isn't it a "Open Source Computer Vision" library? Which is not a 3D math library?

Comment: It allows you to do all the operations mentioned above and more. Computer vision, involves a lot of 3D math, btw.

Comment: I believe that any more specific library will be more sutable for "rotation, translation, perspective projection, everything basically". If you just need to draw rectangle and rotate it then there is nothing about CV here.

Comment: OpenCV handles the OP's *stated* needs. If it's excessive for the OP, I've recommended SciPy as well.

Comment: +1 Why the downvote? OpenCV seems to do all the operations the OP asked for.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Didn't read last part of the question.

Comment: Thanks, this is why I think comments are required on downvotes, else there's no feedback for the person who posted the answer.

Comment: @Jacob - since 3d operations are a question in OpenCV, could you post some links to some of the specific functionality.  For example, the OP wants "feed a library x,y,z coordinates and recieve the x,y screen coordinates", what function is useful for that?  And 3d rotations, etc?

Answer (score 5):

[transformations.py](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/code/transformations.py.html)

A library for calculating 4x4 matrices for translating, rotating, reflecting,
scaling, shearing, projecting, orthogonalizing, and superimposing arrays of
3D homogeneous coordinates as well as for converting between rotation matrices,
Euler angles, and quaternions. Also includes an Arcball control object and
functions to decompose transformation matrices.

Authors:
  Christoph Gohlke http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/
  Laboratory for Fluorescence Dynamics, University of California, Irvine

Answer (score 2):

is SAGE any use to you?
http://vnoel.wordpress.com/2008/05/03/bye-matlab-hello-python-thanks-sage/

http://www.sagemath.org/

Comment: thanks for the recommendation, but sage looks like numpy/scipy to me, ive gone through its documentation, seen some examples, and its not aimed at 3d math but at math in general. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on one now.
https://github.com/adamlwgriffiths/Pyrr

It uses numpy for speed.
The aim is to provide a pure python 3D maths lib.

I'm avoiding external libs because I'm sick of having to follow complex software installs. Python should be easy.

Answer (score 2):

python-math3d is another good 3D mathematic library which is object oriented
https://github.com/mortlind/pymath3d

import math3d as m3d

v = m3d.Vector(1,2,3) # A vector object

o  = m3d.Orientation.new_euler((1,0,0), "ZYX") # An Orientation object from one type of euler angles

t = m3d.Transform(o, v) # A Transform object created using the vector and orientation

t2 =  m3d.Transform()# Another Transform object (Identity)

t2.orient.rotate_x(3) # rotate the transformation around x

res = t * t2 #Matrix multiplication

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I need, many thanks for posting the answer

Answer (score 1):

What about [PyGame](http://www.pygame.org/tags/3d)?  I never used it, but it may contain what you're looking for.

Comment: 1.) pygame is 2d
2.) pygame is trying to draw to  the screen , which is not what i want
3.) pygame is not a math library its an SDL wrapper
4.) no, pygame doesn't contain what im looking for
thanks anyway

Comment: @spearfire: If you click on the link I gave, you get a page with 3D programs that use PyGame.  Maybe some use what you are looking for?  I was just trying to help by throwing an idea!

Comment: I would add that pyeuclid is compatible with PyGame and seems to be really close to what you want.

Comment: @EOL just checked out pyeuclid, perfect.thanks for the help pyeuclid seems to be exactly what i want, not pygame/pyopengl. thanks for that.

Comment: @spearfire pygame has [3D support](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector3). You're not required to draw to the screen using it. You can use the [`pygame.math` module](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html) directly to do your math without any visualization. The `pygame.math` portion of pygame is indeed a math library and not an SDL wrapper. While it does not support projection, it is clean, and supports [rotation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector3.rotate) and translation (through the overloaded `+` operator), among other features.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [MayaVi](http://code.enthought.com/projects/mayavi/). Please take a look at the given link. It does almost everything you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

http://cgkit.sourceforge.net/doc/index.html

The implementation isn't always the best, but it includes quaternions as well as the standard matrix and vector types.  I've used it for tools on a couple commercial game projects.